# How to automatically update Windows definitions of daylight saving times in various countries without doing Windows update

Tags: windows, dst

We have a Windows server application that has to be aware of daylight saving times (DST) in various countries.
(Note: This is not a question about setting the correct daylight saving time for the computer itself)

In order to be up to date, Windows updates sometimes also include updates to the DST meta definitions.
This is important if for instance a country suddenly decides to change the rule when DST will start from  first Sunday of April to second Sunday of April.

However, as this is a production server, automatic windows update is disabled.

Microsoft issues from time to time patches with such changes, that can be applied without Windows-Update. For each of this patches however, a new Microsoft KB is created, with its own proprietary URI, which makes automatic updates impossible.

Question: How can we schedule a task, which periodically downloads and applies all patches

Comment: "How can we schedule a task, which periodically downloads and applies all patches", umm, you just described automatic Windows Update.

Comment: Is this a programming question?  What language is the application written in?  Can you modify the program?

Comment: Yeap, "sounds" like  Windows Update.
But as stated, we cannot use that

Comment: Matt, this is a question of updating Windows with new dst-meta data.
Yes by incidence this is a .net program we could(!) change.
The issue is that that program is already correctly DST-aware, but for acting on correct DST it depends on OS having correct DST-meta data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update Windows automatically without running Windows Update, or selectively tell Windows to only update time zone data?  NO - sorry, there is no mechanism for that.

You could manually watch the RSS feed for [the Microsoft Daylight Saving Time & Time Zone Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dst2007/) and apply updates yourself, but there is no programmatic way to do that.

Since you mentioned in comments that your application is .NET and you can modify it, I'll provide another option for you.  (Incidentally, without this aspect of the problem, your question would be [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

The usual way to deal with time zones in a .NET application is with the `TimeZoneInfo` class, which relies on Windows to have current time zone data.  However, there is another option, you could write your application to use the [IANA time zone database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) instead of the Windows time zone data.  The differences between these two data sources are covered in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) under the "Time Zne Databases" section.

In .NET, by far the best way to work with the IANA database is through the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library.  I encourage you to read through [the user guide](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/) to understand how to use this library in your application.

Assuming you've updated your application to use Noda Time instead of `TimeZoneInfo`, you can now follow the directions [here](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/tzdb.html) on how to keep it updated with the latest time zone data.  Essentially, you can ping a URL periodically (daily, weekly, etc.) to see if there is a newer version of the tzdb available in Noda Time's .NZD format.  You could easily write your app to download the new data file and install it.  Now you've removed the dependency on Windows time zone data, and thus no longer need to concern yourself with Windows Updates or time zone hotfixes.